# Prevent Cupertino tabs to hold the state when switching tabs

Tags: flutter, tabs, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

The default implementation of Material's Scaffold & BottomNavigationBar is to destroy and re-create each tab in each tab change.

In the case of CupertinoTabScaffold, CupertinoTabView and CupertinoPageScaffold the behavior is different: the state of each tab is maintained, so switching between tabs won't re-trigger the initState() method of the tab in each change.

My question is: how to modify this behaviour to act the same as Material? I want each tab to be destroyed and re-created, thus calling the initState() method in each tab change, same as with the Material Widgets.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi There. Post samples as to how your code looks like as of now. What kinds of a structure are you following ?

Answer (score 4):

I would say this is a hack, but one way to actually have elements rebuild is to just use new elements.

But obviously, you need the same widget class to be rendered, so how can it be new ?

`Keys`.

Flutter check the `type` of your widget as well as it's `key` (if provided) to validate whether an `widget` is same or not so as to rebuild.

You can use keys this way. Consider this simple example.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CupertinoTabScaffold(
    tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.calendar)),
      ],
    ),
    tabBuilder: (_, i) => Sample(
      key: ValueKey(Random().nextInt(255)),
    ),
  );
}
```

I have a `Sample` class which I am using to build each screen in the `CupertinoTabScaffold`. But instead of using it like `Sample()`, I have passed an extra `key` parameter which is just a random number.

Now, my `Sample` class looks like this,

```
class Sample extends StatefulWidget {
  Sample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SampleState();
  }
}
```

Now, even if you change something in your `SampleState` class and then visit another `Tab` and then comeback to the previous `Tab`, since you are using a new `Key`, Flutter will think it is a new `Widget` and will rebuild it.

Problem solved.

However, I must ask, why though ?

Comment: I want this behaviour because each tab must load the current data when switching, so I can go to tab A, change something, then go to tab B, the change made in tab A can impact tab B.

Comment: I see. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Wow, I found a strange behavior when using the unique key. If I try to open two dialogs in a row a FlutterError is thrown when trying to open the second dialog when getting the context: framework.dart#909("his widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct). Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active."). This only in a CupertinoApp context, not in Material App. If I delete the uniquer key the error vanishes. I cannot apply your solution without fixing this :(

Comment: I am thinking of sending a stream event to the tab so it refreshes by itself, I was trying to avoid this solution but I think I will do it.

Comment: That's weird. How are you opening a dialog ? Can you post your full code using pastebin ?

Comment: Yes, it's something like that: https://pastebin.com/6WinC9cv

Comment: No no. I mean could you give, reproducible code ? Maybe just the widget code where this function is being used.